os.remove works but Shell:Run with luacom doesn't
I have a file at c:\test.mp3. Removing it with os.remove("c:\\test.mp3") works but I want to remove it with del command from luacom's Shell. Unfortunately, it doesn't work:
local command = string.format('del "c:\\test.mp3"')
local Shell = luacom.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell:Run(command, 0, false)

It returns COM exception:(luacom\src\library\tLuaCOM.cpp,386):The system cannot find the file specified.
Running other operations on this file from WScript.Shell, i.e. using ffmpeg (with the exact same path) have no issues finding this file.
